# sending message C2DM to google server get error

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I try to test c2dm app. I have sign up for Android Cloud to Device Messaging. http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html

I register from my app and sender id to c2dm service and i get registration_id.

After that my third party server must get ClientLogin authentication using email and password. But when i use the registration_id and authorization_id to send message to C2DM Server, i got response AccountDisabled. What does it means? Can you show me how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's problems with ClientLogin (in the end of page):
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html